# marking a item "done" in localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have an application where I am adding li elements to the web page. I need to change the class name of the element to "done" inside of local storage when I mark it as "done" on the webpage. (It should say done: true). With my current code I am unintentionally making two items in local storage, one which is done: true and the other which is done: false. I'll show my code here:

```
function updateDone(e) {
  var spanClicked = e.target;
  var id = spanClicked.parentElement.id;
  var done = spanClicked.parentElement.className;
  spanClicked.innerHTML = "&nbsp;&#10004;&nbsp;";
  spanClicked.setAttribute("class", "done");
  var key = "todos" + id;

  for(var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
    if(todos[i].id == id) {
      var mark = todos[i];
      mark.done = true;
      console.log(mark);
      spanClicked.setAttribute("class", "done");
      var newKey = JSON.stringify(mark);
      localStorage.setItem(key, newKey);

      if(mark.done == false) {
        spanClicked.setAttribute("class", "not done");
        spanClicked.innerHTML = "not done";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

They are both labeled with the same id which is how I keep track of each item, yet there are two of them. Also, when i refresh the page there are two list items shown, one which is marked done. My question is how do I prevent another item from being created and instead mark just one item as done in localStorage?

Comment: a [live-example](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be handy

Comment: Actually, a live example would be necessary to diagnose the problem because from looking at this code I don't know how events you fire or anything. Put the markup and the javascript into something like jsfiddle and you will get help!

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to uniquely identify each item, so you can ensure your marks are being set on the items you intend and are not overwriting because you might have, say, two items with the same key. Since you are *looping through a list*, maybe you can change your keys to be composed of two parts.

`var parent_key = "todos" + parent_id;`

And then, in the loop :

`var store_key = parent_key + ":" + i;`
`...`
`localStorage.set(store_key,newKey);`

This way (so long as the order is going to be consistent), you can separate multiple list elements from the same parent.

As commented, a live example in jsFiddle or something would help better address your requirement.

However if this solution is insufficient you could try the following idea, effectively setting a "table" within localstorage.

```
var parent_key = "todos" + id;
var parent_table = {};
// for loop
    parent_table[i] = newKey;
// end of for loop
localStorage.set(parent_key,parent_table);
```

So you have a table inside of local storage, to give you finer granularity.